# docker-compose build environment variable

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**TL;DR :** How can I pass env variable when building the image with `docker-compose` and have `docker run image command` recognize them ?

I have this Dockerfile :

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:10
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual builds-deps build-base python &&\
    yarn global add nodemon &&\
    yarn &&\
    apk del builds-deps build-base python
```

and this docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3.3"
services:

  api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-preprod
    image: registry.git.louis-girones.fr:4567/make-your-night/back:preprod
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    ports:
      - "${PORT_PREPROD}:${PORT_PREPROD}"
    command: sh -c "mkdir -p dist && touch ./dist/app.js && yarn run start"

  mongo:
    image: mongo:4.0
    ports:
      - "${MONGO_PREPROD}"
    command: mongod
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data/db

  elasticsearch:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.1.1
    volumes:
      - ./esdata:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    environment:
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - "ES_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - "9300:9300"
      - "9200:9200"

volumes:
  esdata:
```

With this .env file (which is in the root folder, like docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile) :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

NODE_ENV=development
PORT=9000
SECRET_SESSION=superSecr3t
APP_NAME=Night Vision
API_VERSION=/api/v0/
DEFAULT_TZ=Europe/Paris
ASSETS_URI=http://localhost:9000/public/img/
BCRYPT_WORKFACTOR=1
ES_PORT=9200
ES_LOG_LEVEL=trace
```

And this code in the node server startup :

```
// Export the config object based on the NODE_ENV
// ==============================================
const config: IConfig = commonConfig

if (commonConfig.env === 'development') {
    _.merge(config, developmentConfig)
} else if (commonConfig.env === 'test') {
    _.merge(config, testConfig)
} else if (commonConfig.env === 'preproduction') {
    _.merge(config, preproductionConfig)
} else if (commonConfig.env === 'production') {
    _.merge(config, productionConfig)
} else {
    throw new Error('Please set an environment')
}
```

When I run the `docker-compose build` command, everything is fine, but for instance If I try `docker run myimage yarn run test` the Error "Please set an environment" is thrown.

I would expect that

```
env_file:
  - .env
```

makes the env variables of this file accessible in my image but that is not the case, that's why I tried to add

```
 environment:
  - NODE_ENV=development
```

But still no success, I have also tried to pass my env variable as command line argument when I run the build :

`docker-compose build --build-arg  NODE_ENV=development api`

But it gives me this message :

```
[Warning] One or more build-args [NODE_ENV] were not consumed
Successfully built 9b14dd5abc3f
```

And I would really prefer to use the first or second methods

docker version : 18.06.1-ce
docker-compose version : 1.19.0

Comment: Open your container and type `echo $NODE_ENV` and see the result. Is it `development`?

Comment: @alex-karshin (not sure how to tag user on answer in comment...) Nope it is a blank line

Comment: Okay, try to remove `#!/usr/bin/env bash` from the first line. I think that's your issue.

Comment: Actually someone answered with telling me to add `ENV NODE_ENV=development` which worked but I didn't have the time to accept it, and I would really prefer something like `ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}` which doesn't seems to work

Comment: Even with `#!/usr/bin/env bash` the echo $NODE_ENV still show a blank line, thanks for your help though

Answer (score 157, accepted):

There's a note [in the docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment):

> **Note:** If your service specifies a build option, variables defined in environment are not automatically visible during the build. Use the args sub-option of build to define build-time environment variables.

It's also [described in here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args). First (as mentioned above), you need to specify `ARG` in Dockerfile:

```
FROM mhart/alpine-node:10
ARG NODE_ENV
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN apk --no-cache add --virtual builds-deps build-base python &&\
    yarn global add nodemon &&\
    yarn &&\
    apk del builds-deps build-base python
```

And then edit your `docker-compose` file to include the argument during build, like so:

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-preprod
  args:
    - NODE_ENV=development
```

Or even

```
build:
  context: .
  dockerfile: Dockerfile-preprod
  args:
    - NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
```

Comment: @Arkemlar for the latter case to work you need to have `NODE_ENV` to be set in your own environment at all times.

Comment: How do we do the same with env file ?

Comment: @AdharshM unfortunately, docker-compose does not support this. Only thing you can do is `source .env && docker-compose ...`. I know i"m late, but this may help. More info https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/5600

Comment: New to Docker and spent several evenings stuck on this. You're answer fixed it in 2 minutes, thanks!

Comment: Aren't compose file build `args` supposed to be specified as `NODE_ENV: development` or `NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}`?

Comment: @GregorEesmaa it's a yaml file, you can use a linter to see both ways are okay

Comment: It needs to be a string, not NODE_ENV: development

Comment: @dhvcc that is wrong. See my answer below.

Comment: Took me hours to realize docker compose *environment* is for runtime

Answer (score 24):

As per documentation under [build args](https://docker-docs.netlify.app/compose/compose-file/#args).

> You can omit the value when specifying a build argument, in which case its value at build time is the value in the environment where Compose is running.

```yaml
args:
  NODE_ENV:
```

Additionally, it will use the `.env` file as documented under [variable substitution](https://docker-docs.netlify.app/compose/compose-file/#variable-substitution).

> You can set default values for environment variables using a .env file, which Compose automatically looks for. Values set in the shell environment override those set in the .env file.

So you can create a `.env` file like below.

```
NODE_ENV=production
BASE_URL=/foo/bar/
```

And then just list them in the compose file either under `build.args` to make them available on *build*, or under `environment` to make them available on *run*.

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      # these are available on build
      args:
        NODE_ENV:
    # these are available on run
    environment:
      BASE_URL:
```

This is kind of useful. However, the problem that comes along with this approach is that if the variables are not set from shell or env file, the default values in the Dockerfile will be overwritten with an empty value.

If one wants to keep some sort of default, the following can be used.

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  app:
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV:-dev}
    environment:
      BASE_URL: ${BASE_URL:-http://localhost:8080}
```

This is making usage of [posix parameter expansion](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02). If the variable is not set, it will use the value after `:-`. So in the example above, it would default to `NODE_ENV=dev` and `BASE_URL=http://localhost:8080`, if those are not set.
Allowing to override them with a `.env` file or by setting a shell variable, i.e. `export NODE_ENV=prod`.

If you want to change the env file it's using, you can do that with the --env-file flag.

```sh
docker compose --env-file .my-env up
```

Comment: I think the environment should be like this. `BASE_URL=${BASE_URL:-http://localhost:8080}`

Comment: @nk18, environment has 2 syntax forms. Mapping and Array. I am showing mapping here. You can use array, as you intend, but then you need to use a leading dash `-`.

Comment: this doesnt work with build

Comment: @mike01010, what exactly doesnt work? As far as I can tell, what is written here is exactly the way it works. Matter of fact, I have done it countless times already.

Comment: @TheFool disregard - i was having troubling with docker-compose build (instead of 'up') using the --env-file parameter. i think it is working now

Comment: @mike01010, `--env-file` is a global flag. It works for all compose commands. Or at least its supposed to.