# docker-compose load .env from dynamic path

Tags: docker, docker-compose, env-file

I have below structure

[image]

The project root `.env` defines the path to either `./docker/dev/.env` or `./docker/prod/.env` as depicted below:

```
environment=dev
dot_env_path=./docker/dev/.env
```

My docker-compose.yml contains the below service snippet:

```
services:
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        restart: always
        env_file: ${dot_env_path} <--notice this variable points to the actual .env
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
            - MYSQL_USER=${MYSQL_USER}
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD=${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
        ports: 
            - 3306:3306
        expose: 
            - 3306
        volumes:
            - db-tmc:/var/lib/mysql
```

However, when I do `docker-compose` build I receive below warnings; it's not detecting the `${dot_env_path}` and loading it's content

[image]

Any idea, much appreciated?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429984/docker-compose-build-environment-variable

Comment: No because those are for build args. OP is actually asking for something else here. A problem with the env_file option..

Answer (score 1):

Dont use `environment:` if you are using the `env_file` option. It overrides the variables already added to the environment from the `env_file:` option

Use this instead.

```
services:
    db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
        restart: always
        env_file: ${dot_env_path}   
        ports: 
            - 3306:3306
        expose: 
            - 3306
        volumes:
            - db-tmc:/var/lib/mysql
```