# forward exact environment variables from host to container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I am finding my self repeating like this:

```
services:
  noice-service:
    environment:
      - EUREKA_SERVICE_URL=${EUREKA_SERVICE_URL}
      - ZIPKIN_BASE_URL=${ZIPKIN_BASE_URL}
      - CONFIG_SERVER_URL=${CONFIG_SERVER_URL}
```

I have defined these env vars in .env file and some in another scripts and I just want to pass their exact value in container. Is there any way quicker way of achieving this without any custom shell script as entrypoint ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [docker-compose build environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68831814/9208887)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the variables directly:

```
# .env
DOTENV=foo
```

```yaml
# docker-compose.yml
version: "3.7"
services:
  busybox:
    image: busybox
    command: ["env"]
    environment:
      - DOTENV
      - ANOTHER
```

And run `ANOTHER=bar docker-compose up`.