# Unable to get env variable from docker compose in dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, ethereum, go-ethereum

I am working on dockerfile for ethereum chain deployment. I finished dockerfile with hardcoded parameters, but when I reference this parameters as environment variables some unclear issues have been rose.

Here is a Dockerfile:

```
FROM ethereum/client-go:v1.10.1

COPY ./chain/accounts/swap.ethash.genesis.json /tmp

COPY ./chain/accounts/boot.key /tmp

RUN mkdir -p /tmp/keystore

COPY ./chain/accounts/keystore/${NODE_ACCOUNT_PWD_FILENAME} /tmp/keystore

RUN geth --datadir /tmp init /tmp/swap.ethash.genesis.json \
    && rm -f ~/.ethereum/geth/nodekey 

COPY ./test-pwd.sh /tmp 
RUN chmod +x ./tmp/test-pwd.sh && ./tmp/test-pwd.sh

RUN geth --unlock 0x367103555b34Eb9a46D92833e7293D540bFd7143 --password /tmp/pwd.txt --keystore /tmp/keystore

ENTRYPOINT ["geth"]
```

I would like to avoid hardcoded parameters and put them into `.env` file which is referenced under the docker compose:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  geth-bootnode:
    hostname: geth-bootnode
    env_file:
      - .env
    image: geth-client
    build:
      context: .
      args:
        - ACCOUNT_PASSWORD=${ACCOUNT_PASSWORD}
        - NODE_ACCOUNT_PWD_FILENAME=${NODE_1_ACCOUNT_PWD_FILENAME}
        - NODE_ACCOUNT_PWD=${NODE_1_ACCOUNT_PWD}
        - NODE_ACCOUNT=${NODE_1_ACCOUNT}
    command:
      --nodekeyhex="c26d705bd5933bc2be72813f1b74f140aa6b3726d2a71a43b163a5c084e9dcb4"
      --nodiscover
      --ipcdisable
      --networkid=${NETWORK_ID}
      --netrestrict="172.16.254.0/28"
    networks:
      priv-eth-net:
networks:
  priv-eth-net:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      config:
      - subnet: 172.16.254.0/28
```

Reference this env var, e.g. `geth --unlock ${NODE_ACCOUNT}`, gives an error of missed parameter:

```
> [9/9] RUN geth --unlock ${NODE_ACCOUNT} --password /tmp/pwd.txt --keystore /tmp/keystore:
#0 0.397 invalid command: "/tmp/pwd.txt"
```

Some users [mentioned](https://gist.github.com/reitzig/4a1cccc965b50a15868fb345d770cdec) it should be converted into `ENV` variable to be available under Runtime, but it gives similar error.

Similar issue happened with `ENV var` for a password and this is a reason why preparation of `pwd.txt` was wrapped into a shell script.  `.env` file parameters names and actual values are double checked.

In my perspective, reference variables like ${NODE_ACCOUNT} and ${NODE_PWD} should be enough; if the runtime visibility scope is an issue, then `ENV node_acc=${NODE_ACCOUNT}` and `ENV node_pwd=${NODE_PWD}` should work. However, neither any of this options doesn't give me successful account unlock and terminate container with an error.  Do I miss something here?

Comment: You are setting build arguments in your `docker-compose.yaml`, but you have not declared any build arguments (using `ARG`) in your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: [docker-compose build environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52429984/docker-compose-build-environment-variable) discusses `ENV` vs. `ARG` a little more.  However, if you build the image with a specific `NODE_1_ACCOUNT_FILENAME` value, that specific file will be "baked in" to the image; the image isn't normally rebuilt if you rerun the container with different options.  A bind mount for the file in `/tmp/keystore` might be a better approach.

Comment: @larsks, thank you. I missed the point then ```ENV``` vars from docker should be mirroring in a Dockerfile. ```ARG``` as entrypoint variable for ```ENV``` variables.

Comment: @DavidMaze, in my perspective if I define ```ARG NODE_ACCOUNT``` and pass different environment variables from each service in ```docker-compose.yaml```, then image will pick up the actual value behind ```ARG```. Do you want to say it doesn't work this way?

Comment: I'm saying, if you change those account values and then try to re-run the container stack without rebuilding the images, it will use the old values.  You'll run into similar trouble if you `docker push` the images to a registry and try to run them on another system without having access to the source code.

Comment: @DavidMaze, thank you, got it. Would ```docker compose up --build```  solve this issue? Launch with this flag should always rebuild images.

Comment: In the same way you don't recompile Docker every time you run it on a different container, you shouldn't have to rebuild your image either.  Rebuilding the image every time will work, but it'll be slow and hard to use in some environments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final solution would look like this:

```
FROM ethereum/client-go:v1.10.1

ARG NODE_ACCOUNT
ARG NODE_ACCOUNT_PWD

COPY ./chain/accounts/swap.ethash.genesis.json /tmp

COPY ./chain/accounts/boot.key /tmp

RUN mkdir -p /tmp/keystore

COPY ./chain/accounts/keystore/${NODE_ACCOUNT_PWD_FILENAME} /tmp/keystore

RUN geth --datadir /tmp init /tmp/swap.ethash.genesis.json \
    && rm -f ~/.ethereum/geth/nodekey 

RUN echo ${NODE_ACCOUNT_PWD} >> /tmp/pwd.txt

COPY ./chain/accounts/entrypoint.sh /tmp

RUN chmod +x ./tmp/entrypoint.sh

ENV NODE_ACCOUNT=${NODE_ACCOUNT}

# This way entrypoint usage would ignore OS signals sent the container. That might cause some issues
# Is it root cause of issue to unable 'geth attach <ip address>'?
ENTRYPOINT ./tmp/entrypoint.sh ${NODE_ACCOUNT}
```

`ENV` vars from `docker-compose.yaml` should be mirrored in a Dockerfile. `ARG` serves as an entrypoint variable for `ENV` variables. Thank you, @larsks, for point out on this!